# How do I read mongodb shell errors?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, mongo-shell

This error doesn't seem to correspond to the data in my editor:

```
SyntaxError: expected property name, got '{' :
@(shell):25:24
```

When I read this I read it as @ row 25 and maybe character 24.
But that doesn't match what's in my editor.
What am I missing?
With previous errors like this, I've found the problem could be anywhere within 5 to 10 rows of what I'm thinking is the row number.
It's clearly not, at least not as it's written in my editor.
How do I interpret the above so I can find the problem?

Comment: I'm not sure if it makes a whole lot of difference, but are you referring to the older `mongo` utility or the newer `mongosh` one?

Comment: apologies for not getting back sooner, it's `mongosh`